# How can I pass an argument into a file that I am requiring in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have two files

```
node_project
    ├── include_me.js
    └── main.js
```

I want to pass arguments into the script `include_me.js` and then run it.

The best I can think of is something like:

include_me.js

```
module.exports = function(arg1) {

    // Script code - does something with arg1

};
```

main.js

```
var arg_to_be_passed = { //..... };

var script = require('include_me');

script(arg_to_be_passed);
```

Would this be correct or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, but you can make it a bit prettier:

```
var arg_to_be_passed = { //..... };
var script = require('include_me')(arg_to_be_passed);
```

This way you save one line, as you need to pass the argument anyway.

Comment: thanks, I guess then you could lose `var script =` and do `require('include_me')(arg_to_be_passed);` since the `script` var now does nothing?

Comment: If it does not return any value, you can skip the variable declaration, sure.